# What are the advantages or implications of using assert vs exit or vice versa?

Tags: c++, c, assert, exit, abort

As far as I understand, a call to `assert(e)`, where `e` is a boolean expression, executes something roughly like `` if (!e) { printf("%s:%d: failed assertion `%s'\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, e); abort(); } `` which terminates the program abruptly if the given expression is not true.

On the other hand, instead of using `assert`, I could probably write something like `if (!e) { fprintf(stderr, "custom error message.\n"); exit(1); }` which naively feels like a more cleaner, nicer thing to do.

Ignoring that `assert` can be turned off globally using the `NDEBUG` flag, what other advantage do you think one has over the other? Have I got the distinction right, or are there conceptual differences between the two which I am unaware of that let the two ways of conditional program termination have their own niche use cases? If the latter, please explain. Thank you.

Comment: `assert` is only useful in debug builds and it's only use is for the developper. The end user should never stumble upon an assert. The advantage of using `assert` is that it will display the filename and the line number of the assert; there maybe more advantages such as it might automatically break into the debugger so you can do further investigations

Comment: @Jabberwocky I am not sure what you mean by "fot zhe developper". I am primarily writing code for my own simulations. So, I am not sure I really understand the philosophical distinction between code for an end user and code for myself.

Comment: "for the developper", sorry for the typo. Press F5, so the corrected comment will be displayed.

Comment: If your program really should stop for some reasons when you're __not__ debugging it, then writing some kind of assert of your own might make sense.

Comment: @Jabberwocky In theory, yes. In practice, asserts (or equivalent) are useful even in production to catch memory flips, CPU bugs and other shenanigans that *will* happen for widespread programs. They should never be triggered by purely logical bugs, yeah, but again, in practice, bugs will happen.

Comment: @Acorn see my previous comment

Comment: Why use both `c` and `c++` tags ?

Comment: Re "*I could probably write something like*", You should be writing error messages to stderr

Comment: @ikegami Right! Absolutely.

Comment: @APJo I primarily code in C++. But I figure this question is equally valid for both C and C++.

Comment: `assert()` doesn't simply exit the application but calls `abort()`. This is usually accompanied with (some kind of) core-dump. So, the core-dump can be loaded afterwards in a debugger to find precisely out where and why the assert didn't hold. (Of course, one could call the `abort()` directly. However, in released S/W we try to prevent any core-dump if anyhow possible. The customers don't like core-dumps.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what other advantage do you think one has over the other?

A macro is used because you want to be able to remove it via conditional compilation. In other words, you don't want the code to even appear in the binary.

> Have I got the distinction right, or are there conceptual differences between the two which I am unaware of that let the two ways of conditional program termination have their own niche use cases?

Well, `exit()` and `abort()` don't behave the same way even if you use `1` as a "unsuccessful" exit code. The latter is intended to kill the program right away without further work and possibly trigger a debugging prompt or save an image of the process space (although exactly what it does depends on the vendor providing it). The former calls the registered functions by `atexit()`. There are other ways of stopping, too, see `quick_exit()` and `_Exit()`.

For C++, there are way more considerations on the behavioral difference, e.g. whether destructors for variables in the stack frame(s) are run, whether global destructors are run, what happens if an exception is thrown while doing that, etc.

Comment: @Scheff That too, yeah (similar to the usual logging functions to avoid evaluating the expression), but the `NDEBUG` requirement already means it needs to be a macro.

Comment: @Scheff No, it cannot, because it is required by the standard that it expands to `((void)0)`, so evaluating the expression is not allowed (nor calling a function). In other words, if it were a function, then `assert(f())` would always call `f()` even if the `assert()` function body is empty in `NDEBUG`. It is the reason why you shouldn't put side-effects there that may change the program behavior in any "relevant" way, and it is the same reason you use macros for logging things: you don't want to evaluate if it is not needed.

Comment: Also maybe that calling `assert` does not pollute your code so much. When reading code it's easier to read over it, because you can better distinguish it from "real" program logic.

Comment: @Scheff Sure, but my point was that a macro is always required no matter how the vendor decides to implement it or if it uses `__FILE__` etc. or not. In other words, if the assert was implemented with compiler magic without using `__FILE__` and the like, they would still have to implement it as a macro if only for the non-`DEBUG` case.

Comment: @Scheff Well, how do you make it expand to `((void)0)` if it is *not* a macro in the `NDEBUG` case?

Comment: For C++, are the behavioural differences implementation specific or in general, `exit` does all the example stuff you mentioned and `assert` does not?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe Pretty much everything is specified in [basic.start.term] of the C++ standard. For example, `std::abort()` does *not* call destructors and does *not* call any registered functions of `std::atexit()` or `std::at_quick_exit()`.

Answer (score 4):

The biggest advantage of `assert` is that it makes one's intentions clear.  If you see `assert(some_condition)` then you know what the author's intent was (i.e., `some_condition` is always `true`).  With your inlined version, I can't assume intention until I actually read your `if` block, and realize you're going to display an error message and terminate the program.

Less important reasons include that `assert` reduces copy/paste errors, `some_condition` is turned into a string automatically (including preservation of variable names), and that tooling can understand it.

Answer (score 0):

'assert' is a code autotesting tool. Sometimes the program should not stop its work with on client side (release version) even if the condition leading to the execution of the assert was met.
For example:

```
   switch(color)
   {
      case red:
        //...
      break;
      
      case green:
        //...
      break;
      
      default:
        assert(false && "unexpected color value. 'enum color' was modified?");
   }
```

another example:

```
   if ( OkOrFailEnum::OK != result )
   {
      assert(false && "data access fail");
      throw std::runtime_error("Can not get index " + std::to_string(index));
   }
```

At the same time, 'assert' is a code commenting tool.

```
   inline unsigned Sum(unsigned* pPos, unsigned* pOffset)
   {
     assert(nullptr != pPos);                             // \
     assert(nullptr != pOffset);                          // | preconditions
     assert(*pPos + *pOffset < *pOffset && "Overflow?");  // /
     
     return *pPos + *pOffset;
   }
```

The assert:

```
 assert(*pPos + *pOffset < *pOffset && "Overflow?");
```

means, that the Sum(..) function does not works correctly with big sums and it have to do some check before call the function.

Comment: @Kazz, Thanks, I have corrected this mistake.